# Why can't Simplex Method solve big equations? Have I forgot something?

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations, linear-programming, simplex, regularization

I just wrote a Simplex Method in pure C-code and I have tested it. It works for the objective function:

$$\max: c^T x$$
With subject to:
$$Ax \le b \\ x \ge 0$$

Here is an example:

```
#include <time.h>
#include "LinearAlgebra/declareFunctions.h"

int main() {

    clock_t start, end;
    float cpu_time_used;
    start = clock();

    double A[2*2] ={3,   3,
                   2,   4};

    double b[2] = {120,
                   150};

    double c[2] = {10,
                  12};
    double x[2];
    linprog(c, A, b, x, 2, 2);

    // Solution
    print(x, 2, 1);

    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((float) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nTotal speed  was %f,", cpu_time_used);
    return 0;
}
```

Solution is:

```
5.000000000000000000 
35.000000000000000000
```

Where $x_1 = 5, x_2 = 35$

I tried to verify and it works!
http://simplex.tode.cz/en/lv4usjgeuxy

My algorithm is built by listen to **patrickJMT** from [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yL7JByLlfrw).
The solution is:

```
#include <time.h>
#include "LinearAlgebra/declareFunctions.h"

int main() {

    clock_t start, end;
    float cpu_time_used;
    start = clock();

    double A[2*3] ={2, 3, 2,
                    1, 1, 2};

    double b[2] = {1000,
                   800};

    double c[3] = {7,
                   8,
                  10};
    double x[3];
    linprog(c, A, b, x, 2, 3);

    // Solution
    print(x, 3, 1);

    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((float) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nTotal speed  was %f,", cpu_time_used);
    return 0;
}
```

Solution is:

```
200.000000000000000000 
0.000000000000000000 
300.000000000000000000
```

Where $x_1 = 200, x_2 = 0, x_3 = 300$

But this Simplex Method only works for "simple" or "small" system equations.

If I try a big $A$ matrix and long $b$ vector, then I need to use regularization.

$$\max : (A^TA + \alpha I)^Tb x$$
With S.t to:
$$(A^TA + \alpha I)x \le A^Tb \\ x \ge 0$$

The problem here for me is that in my [code](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/EmbeddedLapack/blob/master/EmbeddedLapack/src/LinearAlgebra/linprog.c), I have a **do-while** loop that quits if all the negative values in the bottom tableau is equal or above zero(0). But if the matrix $A$ is too big, then I need to increase $\alpha$ to make it solvable. If $\alpha$ is small, then the **do-while** loop will loops for ever and never stop.

**Questions:**

1. Is there another criteria to stop the algorithm?
2. Can I use like an $\epsilon$ in Simplex Method that make sure it will solve? I don't know who to explain, but I have seen lot's of algorithms that using a "small number" here and there because the world isn't perfect and neither the data.
3. Is Simplex Method only suitable for "small" and "easy" data? Is there another algorithm else to use that can handle large matrices?

Here is my [library](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/EmbeddedLapack) if you wonder.

Comment: In the worst case, simplex has exponential time complexity. So depending on your definition of "big," it could take a very long time to solve.

Comment: @Math1000 is it a way to reduce that time? Set an iteration limit or an constant in a if-ststement? I can accept if the solution is not 100% accurate.

Comment: No offense, but the problem is probably somewhere in your implementation, not the simplex algorithm itself. I am no expert in C so I cannot debug your code, unfortunately. You may want to ask on Stack Overflow if there is any error in your code that would be causing it to take a long time to run.

Comment: How large are the "large matrices" you're referring to?

Comment: Are you doing this for educational purposes? If it's for a practical purpose, why not just use a package like Mosek or cplex or something to solve the linear program.

Comment: @littleO try the algorithm. I'm doing this for embedded systems.

Comment: @Math1000 Stack Overflow does not know this math algorithm. I dont think there is a bug inside my code because it working for other type of data. Just not large mats.

Comment: But how large is "large"? That will give a clue about whether or not it should be working. The simplex algorithm should be able to handle fairly large problems.

Comment: @littleO When I simulate it looks like it jumping forward and backward because all the values repeat itself. It feels like it don't find the optimal solution because one iteration it "to much" and other iteration it's "to less" and the steps between these iterations are to large, both forward and backward.

Comment: @littleO Here! https://pastebin.com/a21FQkPH Simulate with those.

Comment: Hmm, the example I see there (if I looked in the right place) has $A$ as a $6 \times 6$ matrix, which would usually be described as a very small problem instance. I think the simplex method should handle such a problem easily. In my mind this increases the probability that there is just a bug in your implementation.

Comment: @littleO Try to write it in here and simulate. The simulation won't even start there as well. http://simplex.tode.cz/en/

Comment: @littleO Solved! Se answer.

Comment: "When I simulate it looks like it jumping forward and backward because all the values repeat itself." - this is known as cycling, and is a well-known problem of the simplex algorithm. Bland's rule is one method used to prevent this from happening.

Comment: @Math1000 thanks for the information. But I solved this problem now by adding an AND and OR gate. But I will definitily look upp blands rule.

Comment: @Math1000 does my answer contains blands rule?

Comment: I can't really answer that. You'd have to look up and see if you're implementing it. There are other methods of preventing cycling as well; that is just the one I learned in school.

Comment: @Math1000 ok. Thank you. I looked up blands rule and it seems that I have been implementing it without knowing that the rule did actually exsist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution. All I need to do is to compare with a AND and OR gate. Pure logical math!

From

```
for(int i = 1; i < row_a; i++){
            value1 = *(tableau + i*(column_a+row_a+2) + pivotColumIndex); // Value in pivot column
            value2 = *(tableau + i*(column_a+row_a+2) + (column_a+row_a+2-1)); // Value in the b vector
            value3 = value2/value1;
            if(value3 < smallest){
                smallest = value3;
                pivotRowIndex = i;
            }
        }
```

To:

```
for(int i = 1; i < row_a; i++){
            value1 = *(tableau + i*(column_a+row_a+2) + pivotColumIndex); // Value in pivot column
            value2 = *(tableau + i*(column_a+row_a+2) + (column_a+row_a+2-1)); // Value in the b vector
            value3 = value2/value1;
            if( (value3 > 0  && value3 < smallest ) || smallest < 0 ){
                smallest = value3;
                pivotRowIndex = i;
            }
        }
```